# Grails Databinding to a Map Property From URL. Custom Data Binder Never Gets Called

Tags: data-binding, grails

I am working on a simple cart application that needs the ability to pass quantities for specific products in the URL. I imagined doing this by having a map property on a command object to keep the data binding simple. However, when I hit my action with a parameter that I would expect to be put into the map, I get the following error:

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Exception occurred when processing request: [GET] /mygrailsapp/action
itemQty[123].id: 5
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at grails.plugin.springcache.web.GrailsFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(GrailsFragmentCachingFilter.groovy:66)
    at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.Filter.doFilter(Filter.java:86)
    at com.infusionsoft.cam.security.filter.BlackListIpAddressFilter.doFilter(BlackListIpAddressFilter.java:78)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

The command object looks like this:

```
class MyCommand {
    Map itemQty

    static constraints = {
        itemQty(nullable: true, blank: true)
    }
}
```

The controller action looks like this:

```
def action = {MyCommand myCommand ->
    // some code
}
```

An example url I am hitting is **/mygrailsapp/action?itemQty[123]=5**

I am following the example from the Grails Docs for binding data to a map, the only difference is I am trying to do so from the URL and not from post like in the docs. I am using Grails 1.3.7. I have tried encoding the brackets - [ and ] - but I get the same error.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit**: I found out that this is occurring because spring expects the map to have the key in it before setting the value and will not insert new entries.

I am now trying to use a custom binder to populate the map but the property editor class methods are never called.

Here is my property editor (I was calling super just to verify that control was getting to the method):

```
class ItemQuantityPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    @Override
    public void setValue(Object value) {
        super.setValue(value)
    }

    @Override
    void setAsText(String text) {
        super.setAsText(text)
    }

    @Override
    Object getValue() {
        return super.getValue()
    }

    @Override
    String getAsText() {
        return super.getAsText()
    }

}
```

Here is the registrar:

```
class ItemQuantityPropertyEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {

    void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry propertyEditorRegistry) {
        propertyEditorRegistry.registerCustomEditor(MyCommand, "itemQty", new ItemQuantityPropertyEditor())
    }
}
```

Here is my entry in resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
    itemQuantityPropertyEditorRegistrar(ItemQuantityPropertyEditorRegistrar)
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try initialising the Map with a commons collections lazy map:

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.MapUtils
import org.apache.commons.collections.FactoryUtils

class MyCommand {
    Map itemQty = MapUtils.lazyMap([:], FactoryUtils.constantFactory(''))

    static constraints = {
        itemQty(nullable: true, blank: true)
    }
}
```

You should not need the custom binding PropertyEditor stuff...